# Make an object stick to the top-right side of the page

Tags: html, css

I added the famous "Fork me on Github" ribbon to one of my projects. The tag looks like this:

```
<a href="https://github.com/Nurdok/htmlify">
    <img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;"
     src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png" 
     alt="Fork me on GitHub">
</a>
```

It looks great, but some of the `div`s on my webpage have minimum length, so when the window is small, one has to horizontally scroll the screen. When that happens, I want the "Fork me on Github" link to stick to the top-right side of the *page*, not the window. This is how it looks right now:

Scrolled all the way to the left:
[image]

Scrolled all the way to the right:
[image]

It seems that the ribbon is placed on the top-right side of the initial window, and stays static.
What I want is for it to be out of sight in the first case and top-right in the second case (when I scroll to the right).

**Edit**: Thanks for the quick answers, people. However, most of the answers made the ribbon scroll horizontally and vertically with the page. What I want is for it to be fixed on the top-right side of the page (*not* the browser view), and only be seen if I scroll to where its position is.

Comment: Is it the first element in the body of your page, or is it a child of another element?

Comment: It's a child, but it can be whatever the answer says.

Comment: @AmirRachum, my answer should do the trick, but is's being downvoted I do not know why :)

Comment: @Wiktor   Same happens to mine (with a fiddle included) Someone must be fulling around....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do a little trick and put your image into a div which has minimal-width.

```
<div style="position:relative;min-width:960px">
 <img src="..." style="position: absolute;right:0;top:0" />
</div>
```

and put that div at the beginning of `<body>` section.

`position:relative` makes that all children of that elements that have `position:absolute` are positioned absolute according to **that** div, not whole page. When viewport is bigger than `min-width`, the div is the same width as the viewport. When the viewport is smaller, the div will have the min-width and the image stays at the corner of the div.

Comment: With a proper choice of the `min-width` value, this solved my problem. I have no idea why it is downvoted.

Comment: It resolved my problem also.. Just want to make it transparent across the div

Comment: you can make fixed position also. <img src="..." style="position: fixed;right:0;top:0" /> Then it doesn't get any issue according to the resolution of window. Some times no nee of <dev> tag.

Answer (score 15):

**Two alternatives**

1. **Sticking to the Viewport**: To stick it to the viewport you should position your element "fixed" instead of "absolute"

```
<img style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;"
```

2. **Sticking to a Container**: And if you want it to be sticked to a container (so youn dont see it when you browse left) use absolute but  do that container position:relative so its containing block is targeted

**If you dont want to see the image when scrolling left** then use a explicit width for this container I am talking about
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Ypa4Y/) example.

I used a squared div instead of an image. CSS code as follows:

```
#container {
   width: 700px;
   height: 700px;
   background: #55ff90;
   position: relative;
}

#image {
   width: 70px;
   height: 60px;
   background: #ffff90;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Then if someone scrolls vertically it will always be visible.

Comment: Got it. See my answer. I included a fiddle

Comment: There is a fiddle showing how it works. Please to anybody voting down be so kind to explain why ?

Answer (score 3):

In case it's supposed to stick to the right top on horizontal scroll only, you can't accomplish this with basic CSS. Your requirement is stick to the right top for horizontal scroll but not vertical scroll. The first part of the requirement can be accomplished using `position: fixed;` though this breaks the second part.

How about always sticking to the right top of the website using a relative float: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQzzB/1/)

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='sticky'>x</div>
</div>

#sticky { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; 
    float: right;
}

#container { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 200px; 
    background: blue; 
}
```

Comment: I want it to stick to the top-right side and stay in place. Unless I can see the top-right corner of the page, I shouldn't see it.

Comment: In case you follow the fiddle, you'll see that this always sticks to the top-right of your website which is your requirement?

Comment: It sticks to the top-right of the browser window, not the page.

Comment: I am not the downvoter... I just wanted to explain why this doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: You're right Amir, fixed it. Notice that this doesn't need positions which is a plus in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `float:right`, adjusting `margin` if you need, e.g.: `margin-right: 5px`. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, you'd like for the image to stick to the top corner of the window UNTIL the window gets to a certain size (horizontally) and then stick.

If so, here is a plausible solution:

```
body{
    min-width:1000px; /* or whatever you need it to be */
}

#ribbon{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtpQX/)

[**DEMO FULLSCREEN**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtpQX/embedded/result/)

You can also use a container div with `min-width`, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed`.

As side note, put the style on the `a` instead of the image and add some `z-index` to make sure it stays on top of everything else:

```
<a href="https://github.com/Nurdok/htmlify" style="position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0; z-index: 999; display: block;">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png" 
     alt="Fork me on GitHub">
</a>
```

Comment: do note that `position: fixed` works a bit differently on mobile due to the way it works - you will actually see the image "jump" after your release your finger, not move while scrolling as it happens on normal web.

Comment: @hexblot Gotta note that `fixed` just works on iOS 5+ and is buggy like you said. I keeps flickering when scrolling. Only on iOS6+ that Apple fixed the `fixed` to be smoother when scrolling.

Comment: +1 for the `z-index` tip - with combination with the accepted solution, it solved my problem. Thanks!